# Is there a size limit to images posted with TinyMCE?

Tags: mysql, image, upload, tinymce, filesize

I am working on a site which includes a blog-type section.  I have a posting system where the input from the editor is sent to a mysql database table.  So far everything works except for when a local image is added.  The image works if it has an extremely small file size, otherwise it doesn't display and sometimes clears everything else in the $_POST['body']. is there a way to allow for larger images?

Here is the php:

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['body'])) {
        include 'php/mysql.php';
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        $title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $date = date('Y/m/d');
        $query = "INSERT INTO posts(title,body,date) 
                VALUES('$title','$body','$date')";
        $insert = runQuery($query,$conn);
        if(!$insert) die($conn->error);
        redirect('News.php');

}

?>

<form id="get-data-form" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="title">Title</label></td>
            <td><input name="title" id="title" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><label for="body">Body</label></td>
            <td><textarea name="body" class="tinymce" id="body">
            </textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Post" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/tinymce/init-tinymce.js"></script>
```

The following is my js code for TinyMCE:

```
tinymce.init({
/* replace textarea having class .tinymce with tinymce editor */
selector: "textarea.tinymce",

/* force_p_newlines : false,
force_br_newlines : true, */

/* theme of the editor */
theme: "modern",
skin: "lightgray",

/* width and height of the editor */
width: "100%",
height: 300,

/* display statusbar */
statubar: true,

/* plugin */
plugins: [
    "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
    "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
],

/* toolbar */
toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons",

/* enable title field in the Image dialog */
image_title: true,
/* enable automatic uplaods of images represented by blob or data URIs */
automatic_uploads: true,
/* add custom file picker only to image dialog */
file_picker_types: 'image',
file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

    input.onchange = function() {
      var file = this.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function () {
        var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
        var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
        var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
        blobCache.add(blobInfo);

        // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };

    input.click();
}
});
```

Comment: If someone knows a way I could alter the above code to upload the image to the '../images/' directory and then have the editor simply refer to that location in the post, that may work better, instead of having the actual image embedded in the mysql data.

Comment: What sizes does it work for and not work?

Answer (score 2):

i face the same problem, solved by changing the column type from TEXT to LONGTEXT

Comment: Semantically and technically `LONGBLOB` would be more suitable than `LONGTEXT` here.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE already has a way to handle inserting local images and getting them to your server:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/

If you configure this on the editor when you `init()` the editor the images will auto-magically get uploaded for you to process when its inserted.  This will get to your end goal of the image being on a server and the `src` attribute just pointing to the image as opposed to having large Base64 images in your HTML content.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm much too newb to understand the information on that page. I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving images in the database, it is better to save them as file in folders.
According to tinymce documents, two approaches are available to upload images in the server.

1. Using `uploadImages()` before form submit

The function - `uploadImages()` - will send all images uploaded to the editor, one by one, to the `images_upload_url` by post method and, will set the scr attribute of that image to the JSON object containing location property.

```
    tinymce.activeEditor.uploadImages(function(success) {
        document.forms[0].submit();
    });
```

and the server should return JSON like

```
{ location : '/uploaded/image/path/image.png' }
```

to set as the src attribute of the posted image. [upload_images](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/)

2. [`images_upload_handler`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_handler)
   It is used if you are going to use your own method with custom logic. 
   The upload handler function takes three arguments: `blobInfo`, a `success` callback, and a `failure` callback. It triggers as an image uploads in the editor and sends the image via an XMLHttpRequest and calls the success callback with the location of the remote image.

   ```
   tinymce.init({
     selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
     images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
       var xhr, formData;

   xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.withCredentials = false;
   xhr.open('POST', 'postAcceptor.php');

   xhr.onload = function() {
     var json;

     if (xhr.status != 200) {
       failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
       return;
     }

     json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

     if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
       failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
       return;
     }

     success(json.location);
   };

   formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

   xhr.send(formData);
     }});
   ```